# How to run GUI application via ssh as another user via sudo

Tags: ssh, sudo

I have ssh configured on my server, and sometimes I have to run some graphical application on it. It works great when I connect with `-X` option. I can run e.g. `google-chrome`. However, if I change user by `sudo -i -u other_user`, I can't run GUI apps as this user.

I assume it is something with environment and DISPLAY, but don't know what to do. I tried to add `-E`, but then I got error message saying that I can't use it with `-i`. How can I run GUI apps via ssh as another user?

Comment: Why do you have a `-i`?  Have you tried removing that?

Comment: Without -i I can only run one command as other user. I want to "become" this user and do stuff as him, and sometimes run GUI app as him. Probably I can also run this GUI app as this user without -i (didn't try), but thats not what I want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `ssh -X` to run commands as the other user. But this makes the applications run markedly slower, even locally.

---

The `-i` option tells `sudo` to reinitialize the environment. X applications require `$DISPLAY` and (on some setups) `$XAUTHORITY`, and may use other environment variable such as locale settings. Try without `-i`, or if you must use `-i`, run

```
sudo -i -u other_user \
  env DISPLAY="$DISPLAY" XAUTHORITY="${XAUTHORITY-$HOME/.Xauthority}" \
  xapplication
```

Even if you get rid of `-i`, you might have to supply `XAUTHORITY` explicitly: by default (if the variable is not set) it's `.Xauthority` in the home directory.

So far I've been assuming the other user could read your `$XAUTHORITY`. But that won't be the case unless you make it so (e.g. with `setfacl -m user:other_user:r $XAUTHORITY`).

Alternatively, rather than let the other user read your `$XAUTHORITY`, you could copy the right cookie to another file that the user can read.

```
xauth extract -f - "$DISPLAY" |
sudo -u other_user xauth -f ~other_user/.Xauthority merge -
```

Note that allowing another user access to your display allows him to do almost anything with it, including sending fake keypresses to applications. So if you were changing users for isolation, you won't get much.